# Can't build working Java app with gRPC, Protobuf and BoringSSL to JAR using Maven

Tags: maven, netty, grpc, grpc-java, boringssl

I have problem with building my `Java` app to `jar` file using `Maven`.

Application is using `gRPC` and `Protobuf`.

When I start my app in `IntelliJ` everything work just fine, problem is when I want to build `jar` with `Maven`... I don't have much experience with creating `pom` files.

I tried to find some solution but nothing works and I ended up with `pom.xml` as below:

```
[...]
<properties>
    <grpc.version>1.17.1</grpc.version>
    <protoc.version>3.5.1-1</protoc.version>
    <netty.tcnative.version>2.0.13.Final</netty.tcnative.version>
    [...]
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
        <version>${netty.tcnative.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    [...]
</dependencies>
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protoc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                </protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                </pluginArtifact>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireUpperBoundDeps/>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>pl.test.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this is the exception when I try to start `gRPC` server with `SSL` context:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the required native library
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.ensureAvailability(OpenSsl.java:346)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.<init>(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:202)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslContext.<init>(OpenSslContext.java:43)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslServerContext.<init>(OpenSslServerContext.java:347)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslServerContext.<init>(OpenSslServerContext.java:335)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newServerContextInternal(SslContext.java:422)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:447)
        at pl.test.grpc.GrpcServer.start(GrpcServer.java:80)
        at pl.test.app.Main.lambda$new$0(Main.java:80)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:85)
        at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:194)
        at pl.test.grpc.GrpcServer.getSslContextBuilder(GrpcServer.java:72)
        ... 3 more
```

I'm building it using command:
`mvn clean compile assembly:single`

Can someone help with creating working `pom` file? The result doesn't have to be single jar file, it might be multiple jars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution, maybe it will help someone deal with the same problem.

We have to add dependency `io.netty.netty-handler` and set compatible versions of `io.grpc.grpc-netty`, `io.netty.netty-tcnative-boringssl-static` and `io.netty.netty-handler` as it is described in table over here https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#netty.

Here's my current `pom.xml`

```
[...]
<properties>
    <grpc.version>1.17.1</grpc.version>
    <protoc.version>3.5.1-1</protoc.version>
    <netty.tcnative.version>2.0.17.Final</netty.tcnative.version>
    <netty.handler.version>4.1.30.Final</netty.handler.version>
    [...]
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
        <version>${grpc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-handler</artifactId>
        <version>${netty.handler.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
        <version>${netty.tcnative.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    [...]
</dependencies>
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.Final</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protoc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                </protocArtifact>
                <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}
                </pluginArtifact>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>enforce</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enforce</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <requireUpperBoundDeps/>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>pl.test.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And now I can build `jar` using command:

`mvn clean compile assembly:assembly`